Append 0 to end of multiple arrays in nested arrays
I saw a previous question about adding to an array and saw that both np.hstack and np.append can be used to do so. My problem is, I am working with nested arrays and I think that is causing a problem. I have an array such as the following:
a = np.array([[(0, 0), (1, 1)]])
and want to change it so that there is a zero at the end of both of the most internal arrays. However, regardless if i do np.hstack or np.append, I get an error saying that the shapes don't match. (ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (2,)). I don't know how to fix this. This is what my code looks like:
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[(0, 0), (1, 1)]])
for i in range(len(a)):
    for r in range(len(a[i])):
        a[i][r] = np.append(a[i][r], [1])
print(a)

This is a simplified example for something more complicated I am trying to do, and so I can't write to a different array because I do not know the size of the starting array. I did try this with the simpler example, and again got the same error message about the shape issue.
If I run the following in the loop:
np.hstack((a[i][r], 1))
It will overwrite itself and so I will only get out the last line from the array instead of the entire array. I want my final answer to look like:
[[ 0 0 1]
[1 1 1]]

I have also tried:
np.insert(a[i][r], -1, 1)
Which gives me the same error.

See this?

First, pay attention to the shape of a:
In [2]: a = np.array([[(0, 0), (1, 1)]])    
In [3]: a.shape
Out[3]: (1, 2, 2)

Rather than describe it as nested arrays, I see that as a 3d array - 3 dimensions.
Now look at what happens in your loop:
In [4]: for i in range(len(a)):    # a.shape[0]
   ...:     for r in range(len(a[i])):   # a.shape[1]
   ...:         x = np.append(a[i,r], [1])
   ...:         print(x,x.shape, a[i,r].shape)
   ...:         
[0 0 1] (3,) (2,)
[1 1 1] (3,) (2,)

a[i,r] is a (2,), 2 element array.  You can append a 1 to it and get a (3,) array.  But you can't put that back into a.  Your error message says it can't write a (3,) into a (2,).
You can do something like this with lists:
In [10]: al=a.tolist()
    ...: for i in range(len(al)):
    ...:     for r in range(len(al[i])):
    ...:         al[i][r].append(1)
    ...:         

In [11]: al
Out[11]: [[[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]

That's adding a [1] to each of the inner most lists.  But numpy arrays can't grow in that incremental way.  Arrays don't grow by appending - you make a new array by concatenating an appropriately sized array.
Now if I create a (1,2,1) shape array:
In [19]: x=np.array([[[1],[2]]])    
In [20]: x.shape
Out[20]: (1, 2, 1)

I can concatenate that to the (1,2,2) to make a (1,2,3):
In [21]: a1 = np.concatenate((a, x), axis=2)    
In [22]: a1
Out[22]: 
array([[[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 2]]])    
In [23]: a1.shape
Out[23]: (1, 2, 3)

np.append with an axis is the same as the more basic concatenate.  np.append is poorly named function, making users think it is a list append clone.  It is not that.

You can just create an array of ones of the same size and append to it.
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[(0, 0), (1, 1)]])
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 1))
print(np.append(a, b, axis=-1))

The output will be:
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 0.]]]


Numpy arrays are fundamentally block-shaped, non-ragged data structures. If you want to append a set of individual elements to some nested arrays, that's impossible. You have to use a list instead. However, if you want to append the same element to every sub-array, that's totally doable.
First make an array of the repeated element:
filler = np.full(a.shape[:-1] + (1,), 1.0)

Then concatenate it with the original:
result = np.concatenate((a, filler), axis=-1)

You can use np.ones or np.zeros to make filler, and np.append for the concatenation.
